# How to force a Trinidad table with rows set, to display the first page/ range?

Tags: jsf, html-table, trinidad

The set up:
A (Trinidad) JSF page with a few inputs and a couple buttons, one of which is "Search."  The action of the search is to take the inputs and use them as search parameters for a call to the database, then displays these in a `<tr:table>` which is hidden until the backing bean returns with the search results.  The table uses the `rows` attribute to break the data into ranges; we have this set to 10, and the search can return over 100 results if the user sets very loose parameters.

The scenario:
The user has done a search and has paged through the table.  The user changes the input parameters and clicks "Search" again.

Desired result:
The new results shown in the table, with the table at PAGE ONE, ie. records 1 through 10.

Actual result:
The new results shown in the table, with the table at whatever page number the user had been on previously.

My question:
The `<tr:table>` does not have any getter/setter for the current page range, at least not that I could find in the documentation.  Is there anything I can do in either the bean or the page, such that when new results are returned from DB, the table goes to the first page/ range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my trinidad tables have bindings and I solved this issue by this:

```
mytable.setFirst(0);
```

mytable is declared as: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.core.data.CoreTable

But this should also work:

```
((CoreTable)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("IdofyourTable")).setFirst(0);
```

I am using trinidad 1.2.14